# Update Serialize data in memcache

Tags: java, php, caching, memcached

I am storing information in memcache like

```
Memcache::set('someKey', array(
'grp1' => 1,
'grpurl1' => 'http://',
'grpname1' => 'Dave'

'grp2' => 2,
'grpurl2' => 'http2://',
'grpname2' => 'Dave2',

'grp3' => 3,
'grpurl2' => 'http3://',
'grpname2' => 'Dave3'
));
```

The array i am showing is having approx 50 keys.

I am currently using associative array to store data in memcache to reduce memory size.

Now u need to update a particular value say grp3 = grp3+1;
So i am thinking of following approaches :

1. Get array in one go .... un-serialize it ... update the array ... serialize it and updates the memcache.
2. I should divide the array and use different keys.(If its not a much of memory concern)

Any other approaches ??

Comment: Don't serialize/unserialize yourself; the memcache interface already does this for you

Comment: Issue is if it has too many keys like 50-100 updating wont'b be an issue ?

Comment: If you need to do regular updates, then store as individual entries in memcache, otherwise you'll find there's more memory and performance overhead as you have to retrieve the large array, update the entry in that, then recache - lots of smaller entries is much easier

Comment: hv u done any benchmarking on this ?

Comment: @MarkBaker Is there an advantage in letting memcache do it for you? I found that if you serialize data in Java and then store just the byte array it works faster.